# parse all subpages of site

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I tried to parse all sub pages of site with cheerio and request. 
Before parsing I think that I need to collect all sub pages urls in an array. 
But I don't understand why my code doesn't do it. Maybe anybody know in what my problem? Thanks for help.

Code that must collect subpages:

```
var validUrls = [];
var expression = /^(\d{1,3}-\d{1,3})/g;
var regex = new RegExp(expression);
var url = "http://www.fullautomatic.ru/index.php/";


if (url.match(regex)) {
    validUrls.push(url.match(regex));
    console.log(validUrls);

}
```

I think code example2 will be better for my task but i can't solve problem

```
var expression = /^(\d{1,3}-\d{1,3})/g;
var regex = new RegExp(expression);
var url = "http://www.fullautomatic.ru/index.php/";


for (var i in url + regex) {
    console.log(regex[i]);
}
```

Comment: `url.match(regex)` returns null.

Comment: Hi İlker. Me need parse in format : url + expression.. how can perform this? I think url.match(regex) matching url with regex (

Comment: Could it be because you are matching the regex against the url of the page instead of the contents of the page?

Comment: me need collect subpages urls, for example http://www.fullautomatic.ru/index.php/100-200  and after that parsing content of all subpages or i dont understand something?